# I am unable to open or edit my software sources

Tags: updates

I want to change my software sources because I don't want to update my Ubuntu from **other software sources**. I tried to change it from Unity dock: I typed `software source` and a icon appeared but when I clicked nothing happened.

And then I tried it from **Update manager**: I clicked on `edit->source` but nothing happened.

I am still able to download and install updates as well as software from **Ubuntu Software Center**

Comment: You could always edit it manually too. The file is at `/etc/apt/sources.list` . Make sure you make a backup copy of the file before you edit it so that you can go back to it if the need arises.

Comment: i am using ubuntu 11.10 with kde-standard

Comment: The apt's sources.list file is always in the same place in every flavour of Ubuntu. So I am pretty sure the file is at `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: i am able to open file list from command line 'sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list'    but how to know which source is offering me other software sources or unsupported sources

Comment: like in GUI i have to do only that  only to uncheck the box which is offering me other software updates

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1958/discussion-between-nitstorm-and-paru38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can open your software from

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

here you will find your software sources

and you can chose your software sources you need every source has its description which is followed by #

you can delete the other software sources

Comment: please make a backup before editing to list

Answer (score 4):

You could give this terminal command a try:
Under GNOME/Unity

```
gksudo software-properties-gtk
```

Under KDE

```
kdesudo software-properties-kde
```

Comment: Dont see any reason for the downvote here, this actually might have worked fine.